# How do I get the about page to work in the angular seed advance project?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-seed

I have been following the instructions on this page https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced#how-to-start. I have gotten everything install and run, when I run npm start I see the index page with Loading...

I also noticed in the src/client/app/components there is an about component with a route. However I am not sure what to do with this. Because the about component has a route should I be able to go to http://localhost:5555/about and see something? because it just shows me the same Loading...

I also tried putting the component  next to  and nested inside  on the index.html page, but again it just prints the same Loading...

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'll just remark that that starter kit looks pretty bloated for someone new to the framework. Try to start simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was getting a javascript error because a dependency was missing. https://github.com/NathanWalker/angular-seed-advanced/issues/354. Once I fixed that the app worked.